# ETW - deleting log file causes logging to break?

Tags: winapi, etw

I have started to use ETW logging as recommended by Microsoft for its high performance and prevent reinventing the wheel etc.

However I've found that if someone deletes the log file then logging simply stops working until the trace session is stopped and restarted. I could live with this if the API's actually returned an error so I could restart it myself, but nothing returns any error code.

My question is - how do I deal with this situation? Is there a way to tell ETW to lock the file to prevent deletion? Should something be returning an error?

Note that I am using the NT5 API level, but this issue is seen on NT6+.

Relevant API's:

```
RegisterTraceGuids
StartTrace
EnableTrace
TraceEvent
```

I was hoping that the control call back might be called when the file was deleted, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the EventSource library, please take a look at Vance Morrison's blog entry, [Why doesn't my EventSource produce any events?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2012/12/21/why-my-doesn-t-my-eventsource-produce-any-events.aspx) The short answer: exceptions are normally swallowed because logging systems should not crash your application. In the blog entry, he explains how to view exceptions that are thrown, by establishing an external trace session. You may wish to periodically poll for the existence of the file, and put out an error report in some way you can detect.

Comment: I'm using raw win32 API so there can't be any exceptions (apart from access violations which would mean a bug in the OS)

Comment: I have been using it from the .net wrapper, and I don't see much information about failures there either. ETW is designed mainly to have the log file creation is a separate process from the event trace generation.

Comment: So you think deleting the log file while its running means it should just silently fail till the next reboot? Even though the ETW session is gone on the next reboot? Seems like a massive flaw to me

Comment: @paulm I don't know the best solution to that problem, but that is the rationale behind the design. Continuing to run the application or service is more important than the logging of it. There is a constructor you can use with the .net EventSource class that will cause it to throw an exception on failure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485655(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @paulm I should add another problem I discovered today: opening a .etl file with PerfView, while the file is being appended in another process, causes the file to stop accumulating events. I had to make a copy of the file first, to keep it from truncating.

Comment: @paulm Maybe contact the MSDN forum. I will do that for the PerfView issue when I have time. Vance tends to respond there.

Comment: @paulm One other possible work around is to maintain a separate text log file in addition to the .etl file, using a process of your own creation. That is simply a backup. Of course it is better to make it harder to delete/lock the .etl file.

Comment: A copy of the file isn't going to solve the problem though.. the user is still going to open the original file and break it

Comment: @paulm Not having used the native API, I cannot say for certain, but with the .net API, which is supposed to be a wrapper, the event source is separate from the event trace session. In this case, it is the event trace session that would be broken, not the event source. Using the .net API you can create an EventListener (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventlistener.aspx) within the same process, and it would keep working, as you have complete control over that.

Comment: Is this creating a "private" session? Can other processes log events to your listener in this case? Confusing how they've changed the terms around in the managed API.

Comment: @paulm StartTrace creates a trace session. A trace session can be in another process or in the same process generating the events, because the event sources uses a kernel object for communication. I don't think there is an equivalent to an EventListener in the native API. The EventListener is specific to one process only -- you cannot listen to another process.

Comment: There are some flags to create the session as private though - where only the same process can listen, that must be what .NET is using?

Comment: @paulm I don't think so, but the person to ask is Vance Morrison.

Comment: @paulm For what it is worth, opening a .etl file with PerfView, using the latest version, no longer causes the file to stop accumulating events. I don't know if the underlying components of ETW are any more robust now with respect to file deletion.

Comment: @paulm I am using windows 7, latest updates, however, most likely the fix was in the PerfView application, not the OS.

Comment: The file delete issue seems to be caused by the kernel holding an open handle to the pending delete ETL file though, so it must have been a kernel side fix..

Comment: @paulm My own issue was not file deletion, which I simply avoid, but rather that opening the .etl file with PerfView caused the file to stop accumulating events.